# Исключить похожие элементы в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Получаем массив с несколькими элементами. В каждом из них есть ключ name и address со своими значениями. Нужно сравнить каждый элемент массива между собой по этим ключам и исключить из массива похожие элементы.

```
    array {
    [0]=> array(16) {["name"]=> string(18) "SuperBussines INC" [0]=> string(18) "SuperBussines INC" ["phone"]=> int(2024445554) [1]=> int(2024445554) ["address"]=> string(22) "ST Street Groove 12 MO" [2]=> string(22) "ST Street Groove 12 MO"}
    [1]=> array(16) {["name"]=> string(18) "SuperBussines INC" [0]=> string(18) "SuperBussines INC" ["phone"]=> int(2024445554) [1]=> int(2024445554) ["address"]=> string(22) "ST Street Groove 12 MO" [2]=> string(22) "ST Street Groove 12 MO"}
    [3]=> array(16) {["name"]=> string(18) "Super INC" [0]=> string(18) "Super INC" ["phone"]=> int(2024445554) [1]=> int(2024445554) ["address"]=> string(22) "ST Groove 12 MO" [2]=> string(22) "ST Groove 12 MO"}
    }
```

- Если name разные, то проверку можно сразу прекратить,
  если похожие,то сверяем address:
- Если address разные, то проверку можно прекратить, иначе
  исключаем элемент с меньшим количеством символов.

Функция, которую "родил" сам проверяет между с собой элементы, НО по порядку первый со вторым. Мне же нужна проверка каждого элемента с каждым, помечая по пути претендентов на удаление и выполнить удаление в конце функции.

```
public static function checkuniq($array)
    {
     $num = count($array);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
                for ($u = $i + 1; $u < $num; $u++) {

                        similar_text($array[$i][0], $array[$u][0], $prc);
                        if ($prc > 80) {

                            similar_text($array[$i][2], $array[$u][2], $prc2);
                            if ($prc2 > 80) {
                                if (iconv_strlen($array[$i][2]) < iconv_strlen($array[$u][2])) {
                                    unset($array[$i]);
                                } else {
                                    unset($array[$u]);
                                }
                                return $array;
                            }
                        } else {

                            return $array;
                        }



                }
            }
}
```

Comment: отсортируйте массив по name и затем адрес, и потом просто последовательно просмотрите. сортировку можно сделать при помощи usort()

Comment: in_array попробуй будет быстрее так как написана на Си ну и array_unique

Comment: Похоже что данные получили из базы данных. Может быть проще решить эту задачу на уровне SQL, чем городить непонятно что на PHP?

Comment: @splash58, сортировку опробую. 
@SergeEsmanovich привел немного неверный пример массива, но in_array и array_unique не подойдут. Значения ключей могут иметь разное написание одного и того же, а не просто часть. То есть мне подойдут только `similar_text` и `levenshtein`

Comment: @Zhenya40 через callback можно задать свои правила сравнения

Comment: @newman верно, из бд. Разве данная задача на sql не решится примерно таким же способом? Дело в том, что бд просто очень большая (500 млн. строк примерно). Не легче ли после запроса некоторой выборки к бд выполнять эту функцию и удалять строки из бд, либо помечать их как проверенные. Постепенно при работе с бд, она сама очистится от похожих значений.

Comment: БД всегда быстрее, а так  array_unique($arr,SORT_REGULAR)

Comment: @Zhenya40 возможно и вариант. Но лучше сделать один раз чистку базы данных, чем "терзать" ее постоянно.

Comment: ещё так можно array_filter

Comment: SergeEsmanovich спасибо, я не против опробовать решить  с помощью array_unique или array_filter, только как им "задать свои правила сравнения" под мою задачу? @newman Если выборки происходят по ключу phone, а затем выполняются нужные мне сравнения, каким способом будет лучше произвести очистку?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько велик ваш исходный массив? Можем мы себе позволить выделить еще столько же памяти? В этом случае можно было бы не помечать для удаления элементы, а выстроить новый с отобранными значениями, а старый массив затем удалить? Ниже пример, как это могло бы выглядеть. Единственное, я не использовал функции similar_text(), а заменил её прямым сравнением

```
<?php
$arr = [
  [
    "name" => "SuperBussines INC",
    0 => "SuperBussines INC",
    "phone" => 2024445554,
    1 => 2024445554,
    "address" => "ST Street Groove 12 MO",
    2 => "ST Street Groove 12 MO"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "SuperBussines INC",
    0 => "SuperBussines INC",
    "phone" => 2024445554,
    1 => 2024445554,
    "address" => "ST Street Groove 12 MO",
    2 => "ST Street Groove 12 MO"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Super INC",
    0 => "Super INC",
    "phone" => 2024445554,
    1 => 2024445554,
    "address" =>"ST Groove 12 MO",
    2 => "ST Groove 12 MO"
  ]
];
// Отбираем все подходящие элементв в новый массив
$new = [];
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  // Вычисляем насколько похож текущий элемент на все уже отобранные элементы
  $tmp = array_map(
    // Передаем текущий элемент через замыкание
    function($el) use($value){
      // Здесь условие сравнения, например, ваша функция similar_text
      return $el['address'] == $value['address'];
    },
    $new);
  // Если хотя бы один элемент похож, не добавляем, все не похожи - добавляем
  $similar = array_reduce($tmp, function($result, $item){
    return $result || $item;
  },
  false);
  // Здесь при необходимости можно заменить
  // существующий элемент более подходящим
  if(!$similar) $new[] = $value;
}
// результат
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
echo "</pre>";
// Старый массив теперь можно удалить
unset($arr);
```

Comment: Исходный массив может включать в себя примерно до 6 элементов, которые нужно сравнить между собой. Памяти можно выделить сколько угодно. :) Спасибо за пример. Сейчас опробую на проекте.